# machine for developing/debugging android apps

Tags: android, android-emulator

My current laptop has Intel Core2 Duo P9500 @2.53GHz with 4GB memory. Running android emulator on Eclipse is quite a pain (very very slow). Any recommended/minimum system requirement for android developers out there?

Right, it does not have a stand-alone graphics card, it has embeded Intel Graphics Media Accelerator GM45.

Comment: I suspect it's you're disk and graphics.

Comment: i have a core duo with only 3 gb, and its not so fast, but i can work perfectly.

Comment: The emulator is notoriously slow anyway, particularly when booting up. You don't actually need to close the emulator, you can just keep "redeploying" your app to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster processor and hard-drive should help.

Honeycomb will run slow on any computer.  But, no matter what you are using, shrinking the resolution of the Emulator/AVD a bit can help.